# Symfony project CMS

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, content-management-system, sonata

I am building a website which uses a symfony backend and a mysql database. I read about the Sonata project and wondered if it would allow me to set up a easy to use cms with a GUI so that the sites content can be maintained without having to hard-code it into the project. Also I would like to keep my projects structure the way it is, I wouldn't like to set up a Wordpress instance. It would be awesome if I could set up the CMS on top of the existing symfony project.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you check out [Symfony CMF](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/index.html)?

Comment: Check out the EasyAdmin bundle in Symfony3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with Sonata Project for a CMS Project, and you can do it, You have the [SonataPageBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle)

And you have other solution : [KunstmanBundle](https://bundles.kunstmaan.be) , It's perfect for CMS project 
Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Can build your own using SonataPageBundle; OR
2. Just add admin views for certain entities using SonataAdminBundle; OR
3. Use any of the existing CMS projects in Symfony (i.e. https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/index.html)

And if you just need a cms built using symfony components: https://symfony.com/projects/category/cms